# Is It a bug that Visual Studio marks it as an error but when it runs it works completely fine?

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor, .net-5

Im Currently Testing around with Blazor and noticed this weird behaviour and wanted to know if its a know bug or even intentional.
Its pretty normal that visual studio marks something as an error but after building the error is gone but in this case the error stays. I got this code at the beginning:

```
<p>@Test2</p>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like

```
<TestComponent Test1="@test1" Test2="@test2"/>
@code {
    string test1 = "abc";
    string test2 = "cba";
}
```

but now if i change the type of test1 or 2 it breaks. lets say i change it to int in the Component and the call like this:

```
    [Parameter]
    public int Test2 { get; set; }
```

and

```
int test2 = 2;
```

Now the error is there and i haven't found a way to get rid of it. It just says on the bind of Test2

> CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

Is there any reason why Visual studio should behave like this or is it just simply a bug?
if it is, where would i file a report?

Comment: the error should contain the originator (extension) of the error, see the PROBLEMS panel, you can file an issue there

Comment: I have seen this problem frequently in my Blazor apps.  I believe the intellisense for Blazor is a little buggy, where as the compiler is rock solid and will only generate error if there is a real error.  Visual Studio 2019 Preview has a new text editor for Blazor which I suspect will work better.

Comment: One trick that sometimes works here is to close the .razor file and reopen it.  Sometimes the intellisense error will go away.